# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following SQL Server cursor code segments to insert data

```
     -- declare a cursor 
        DECLARE insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor CURSOR FOR

        SELECT * FROM Account_APOrderDetail WHERE APOD_Master_Id = @var2;

        -- open cursor and fetch first row into variables
        OPEN insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor INTO
          @Ref_Code,
          @Create_UserId,
          @Create_Date,
          @Modification_UserId,
          @Modification_Date,
          @CompanyId  

        -- check for a new row
          WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
          BEGIN

        -- do complex operation here
          INSERT INTO Account_APInvoiceDetail
          SELECT @Ref_Code,
          @Create_UserId,
          @Create_Date,
          @Modification_UserId,
          @Modification_Date,
          @CompanyId

        -- get next available row into variables
        FETCH NEXT FROM insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor INTO @Ref_Code,
          @Create_UserId,
          @Create_Date,
          @Modification_UserId,
          @Modification_Date,
          @CompanyId

        END
        close insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor
        Deallocate insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor
        GO
```

But I got following error msg here

> 'Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 128
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: No any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: provide the columns name with the insert statement

Comment: provide column name after `INSERT INTO Account_APInvoiceDetail`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of number of columns in the Account_APInvoiceDetail tables does not match with the select statement.

You should specify column names while inserting the record like below and it will work.

```
  INSERT INTO Account_APInvoiceDetail
(Ref_CodeColumnName, Create_UserIdColumnName, Create_DateColumnName, Modification_UserIdColumnName, Modification_DateColumnName, CompanyIdColumnName)
          SELECT @Ref_Code,
          @Create_UserId,
          @Create_Date,
          @Modification_UserId,
          @Modification_Date,
          @CompanyId

        -- get next available row into variables
        FETCH NEXT FROM insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor INTO @Ref_Code,
          @Create_UserId,
          @Create_Date,
          @Modification_UserId,
          @Modification_Date,
          @CompanyId
```

Note: Provide actual column name instead of Ref_CodeColumnName, Create_UserIdColumnName, Create_DateColumnName, Modification_UserIdColumnName, Modification_DateColumnName, CompanyIdColumnName